# How do I know what my primary key should be and what is Indexing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, primary-key

So I have a created a table with 3 columns:

`Name (varchar(5))`, `Date (date)` and `text (varchar(150))`

If there are 40 names and 365 days of the year and each name is associated with each day then what will the primary key be? Will it be the text? since that is what will be unique for each combination of name and date?

Furthermore, what's the difference between an indexable column and non-indexable column?

Comment: This smells like homework with no real effort shown...

Comment: The primary key will be the `identity` column that you define as the primary key.  You can then define unique combinations of keys according to your business rules.  Oh, that is how I would define the table.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals..

Answer (score 1):

If those are really your only options, then `text` would be the primary key. However, typically you would use an auto-generated index/identity (integer) column that would be used as the primary key. If "none of the above" is an option, I would go with none of the above. It may be that this is a simplified question for beginners so text could be the correct answer in that case, but it's really not a good idea to use it as the primary key because I could manually enter duplicates.

The difference between an indexable column and a non-idexable column is that indexable columns do not allow duplicates.